# JDBC AWS - Athena - Specify Database

Tags: jdbc, amazon-athena

I am trying to use Athena with JDBC to execute some SQL queries. I've read a lot how to connect:

```
"jdbc:awsathena://AwsRegion=us-east-1;User=%s;Password=%s;S3OutputLocation=%s"
```

Above is simple example, but how to specify which database I'll connect or execute queries.

When I use this url I catch this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: [Simba][AthenaJDBC](100071) An error has been thrown from the AWS Athena client. TABLE_NOT_FOUND: line 1:15: Table 'awsdatacatalog.default.fc_content' does not exist
```

This table was created in another database and datasource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Page 100](https://downloads.athena.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/drivers/JDBC/SimbaAthenaJDBC-2.1.1.1000/docs/Simba+Amazon+Athena+JDBC+Connector+Install+and+Configuration+Guide.pdf) of the manual you can see how to select the Catalog at connection time.

You can also use fully qualified table names in your queries as an alternative.

Comment: Hi MarcC thanks, after I read the doc these parameters Catalog and Schema worked properly

Answer (score 0):

After read the documentation suggested by MarcC these parameters Catalog and Schema worked

Example the JDBC

```
jdbc:awsathena://AwsRegion=us-east-1;User=%s;Password=%s;S3OutputLocation=%s;Catalog=%s;Schema=%s
```